# How to lower the heater temperature on Kyocera ECOSYS printer?

Tags: printer, laser-printer

We have a bunch of Kyocera ECOSYS printers (mostly P2040dn).

One of the printers started to smear the pages black after working a while with a refilled toner. We contacted the company that sold the printers and refilled the toners. The technician said something along the lines of "we have to set the heater temperature lower". He pressed some magic key combination and from that moment the pages come out perfect.

Now another of the printers is showing the same problem. Can anyone tell how to change the configuration so the pages come out clean again?

We are forbidden to contact the previous company at the moment because of some internal power struggles here.

Comment: Have you check the manual for the printer?  Since you didn't give the model of the printer, causing you problems, only your prints are "mostly of a specific model" which isn't really helpful information.

Comment: @Ramhound The model is P2040dn that we are having the problem with. The user manual did not include this information. We don't have the service manual.

Comment: [I was able to find it without a problem.](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Kyocera-Ecosys-P2235dw-6925369.html), and yes, the manual is applicable to your model.  If it is not documented in those manuals, then Kyocera has not documented it.  You will have to break down and contact them for the information.

Comment: The printers are designed to work with the OEM toner and not be adjusted.  It sounds like you're working with a supplier that is refilling with 3rd party toner that has different characteristics.  The simple solution is to use the real thing that the printers are designed to work with, or something compatible.  You're on your own when you start messing with the design, or internal settings that are not intended to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, smearing the toner is more likely to be caused by a fuser temperature that is set too low. If the fuser is the problem, the smudges will appear with a regular spacing (fuser roller diameter x 3.14). They can appear on the back as well as the front of the paper.

Raising the temperature is much easier than lowering it, as it can be done by specifying heavier paper.

Try telling the printer that the paper loaded is heavyweight paper. Unfortunately, while the specs say it can use heavy paper, the manual does not tell you how to select it. It will be one of the driver settings, so have a look there. Note that Word wants you to select paper type from Page Setup.